# Removing header text aspose cells

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-cells

I'm creating a pdf file using aspose cells. When the pdf file created, there is a text which is `Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Cells for Java.Copyright 2003 - 2016 Aspose Pty Ltd.` . I want to remove it but I don't know how to do it.

How can I do this?

[image: sample]

My codes is here

```
Workbook workbook=new Workbook("C:\\Users\\ftk1187\\Desktop\\DICA.xls");
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
worksheet.getPageSetup().setPaperSize(PaperSizeType.PAPER_A_4_EXTRA);
worksheet.getPageSetup().setOrientation(PageOrientationType.PORTRAIT);
worksheet.getPageSetup().setZoom(75);
worksheet.setTransitionEvaluation(false);
OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\ftk1187\\Desktop\\DICA.pdf");         
workbook.save(out, SaveFormat.PDF);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using and setting a valid license of Aspose.Cells for Java, so your code will be processed in evaluation mode where your output files would always have evaluation watermark, you cannot remove it. See the [document](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Licensing) for reference.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: But we can remove it with code if you have python

Comment: how did you remove it, could you share the details?

Comment: I am sorry You are working at Aspose. I cannot disclose it